# How do I make tree view editable but undeletable?

Tags: xml, odoo-8, odoo

I want the tree view editable while editing, but I want the records to be undeletable. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
<tree delete="false">
   ...
</tree>
```

Add that sentence to the tag `<tree>` in the XML view, and users won't be able to delete the records, but they still will be able to edit them.

Comment: what about preventing adding an item, can I do that also?

Comment: yes, you can write `<tree create="false"> ... </tree>` as well.